# clojure multiple StackOverflowError

Tags: clojure, stack-overflow

I have a clojure script that I've been running for several years now.

Recently I had to do a reinstall of leiningen and java 8.

When I run the code I now get multiple StackOverflowErrors on third party libraries.

E.g.
StackOverflowError   org.apache.commons.math3.util.FastMath.cosQ (FastMath.java:1850)

and

StackOverflowError   clojure.lang.Numbers$DoubleOps.combine (Numbers.java:571)

I would post code but it happens now at multiple points in my code and on third party libraries??

Comment: Well, without seeing *any* code, it's unlikely we'll be able to help you. Post the full stack trace leading to the second error, and a sample of its code. A stack trace is usually the best way to debug a SO, and the second scenario will probably be less convoluted than the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I could not compare the previous setup as it was on a machine that was wiped clean.

I found that an error had crept into one of the math formulas executed by the tool which basically called itself repeatedly resulting in the stack overflow error.

Answer (score 2):

without a stack trace and some code, a specific anser will be hard to find, so here is a general method for these things:

#### Part 1 "what was running before":

recreate your old environment, by digging through the logs, reverting to a backup etc. then run:

```
lein deps :tree 2>&1 > old-lein-dependencies
```

the `2>&1` part ensures that the version range and conflict warnings 
  are included in the output.

Mark down the leiningen version and java version:

```
lein version
```

#### Part 2: "what is running now"

Repeat the steps and record the same information as before:

```
lein deps :tree 2>&1 > new-lein-dependencies
lein version
java -version
```

#### Part 3: Diff and Compare

pick through all the differences

```
diff -u old-lein-dependencies new-lein-dependencies
```

there will be a big block of differences at the top where lein prints all the important warnings. The final clue is almost always here, though it's often not easy to recognise up right away.

#### Part 4: Do Science

go through every version change, starting from the initial configuration by pinning the versions in the project.clj until you find the change that breaks things. A convenient way to pin these is with the `:managed-dependencies` block in the project.clj file. It looks something like this:

```
:managed-dependencies [[http-kit "2.3.0-alpha4"]]
```

and repeat the process of switching out versions till you get a handle on where the change was introduced. For me this has almost always been the result of using a version range in a dependency rather than a specific version. I'm not too enthusiastic about version ranges anymore :-/